# How to reuse react table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to make a react component library so I can use them through out my entire application. I have the first part of the library being a table and this is still in the testing stages but I cannot figure out how to call the component and create it on the page its called. Currently this is how its working. I also just starting programming in React yesterday.

HTML

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/reactcomponents/table.js"></script>
<div id="loadboardContainer">
  <div class="table-desc">Future Loads</div>
  <div id="futureLoadsContainer"></div>

  <div class="table-desc">Todays Loads</div>
  <div id ="todaysLoadsContainer"></div>

  <div class="table-desc">Active Loads</div>
  <div id ="activeLoadsContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Then I have my react component.

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      results: [],
      columns: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      result = JSON.parse(result);

      if(result['resultRows'] == undefined){
        result['resultRows'] = [];
      }

      this.setState({
        results: result['resultRows'],
        columns: $.makeArray(result['resultCols'])
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },
  render: function() {
    // Set array for rows.
    var rows = [];
    var header = [];

    this.state.columns.map(function(cols) {
      header.push(<TableColumns data={cols.cols} key={cols.id} />);
    });

    this.state.results.map(function(result) {
      rows.push(<TableRow data={result.rows} key={result.id} />);
    });

    // Return the table.
    return (
      <table className="table table-condensed table-bordered no-bottom-margin">
        <thead>
          {header}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

// Set up columns
var TableColumns = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var colNodes = this.props.data.map(function(col, i){
      return (
        <th key={i}>{col}</th>
      );
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {colNodes}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

// Set up row
var TableRow = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rowNodes = this.props.data.map(function(row, i){
      return (
        <td key={i}>{row}</td>
      );
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {rowNodes}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var futureContainer = document.getElementById('futureLoadsContainer');
var todaysContainer = document.getElementById('todaysLoadsContainer');
var activeContainer = document.getElementById('activeLoadsContainer');

ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getFutureTableValues.php" />, futureContainer);
ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getTodaysTableValues.php" />, todaysContainer);
ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getActiveTableValues.php" />, activeContainer);
```

And this works when I import the table.js file to the html but I would like it to be more universal in the component usage and remove the

```
var futureContainer = document.getElementById('futureLoadsContainer');
var todaysContainer = document.getElementById('todaysLoadsContainer');
var activeContainer = document.getElementById('activeLoadsContainer');

ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getFutureTableValues.php" />, futureContainer);
ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getTodaysTableValues.php" />, todaysContainer);
ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getActiveTableValues.php" />, activeContainer);
```

to be called in the html/php page like the following.

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/reactcomponents/table.js"></script>
    <div id="loadboardContainer">
          <div class="table-desc">Future Loads</div>
          <div id="futureLoadsContainer"></div>

          <div class="table-desc">Todays Loads</div>
          <div id ="todaysLoadsContainer"></div>

          <div class="table-desc">Active Loads</div>
          <div id ="activeLoadsContainer"></div>
        </div>

var futureContainer = document.getElementById('futureLoadsContainer');
    var todaysContainer = document.getElementById('todaysLoadsContainer');
    var activeContainer = document.getElementById('activeLoadsContainer');

    ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getFutureTableValues.php" />, futureContainer);
    ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getTodaysTableValues.php" />, todaysContainer);
    ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getActiveTableValues.php" />, activeContainer);
```

The first way that is working works fine, but if I remove the ReactDom.renders to the html page I am actually putting the component on it says that Component Table doesn't exist. Is there anyway to do this so later on in the application when I have a table all I have to do is import the table.js react component and connect the source and its there? I have looked at other answers on here but they seem to mainly deal with the data for usability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the table component in your HTML you need to export it using `module.exports` since you are not using  ES6 for React.

```
var Table = React.createClass({
      ...
});
var TableColumns = React.createClass({
...
});

var TableRow = React.createClass({
  ...
});

 //Export the table component
module.exports = Table;
```

Also the thing is that browser don't have support for JSX so you need to use either of `webpack` or `browserify` to transpile your code.

A good tutorial link [Webpack tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack)

Comment: This is telling me module is not defined. Is there some other plugin or something I need to have installed?

Comment: Well the thing is that browser don't have support for JSX so you need to use either of webpack or browserify. A good tutorial link https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack

Comment: I would upvote you but I do not have 15 reputation yet :(

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial link to. I actually like this one its easier to understand than the other ones I have looked at.

Comment: Happy to help :) Its okay if you can't upvote now. You can do that anytime you reach 15 points not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Well you are almost there.

Here's how you should get it done:

Table.js

```
var Table = React.createClass({
      //Everything stays same here
});
var TableColumns = React.createClass({
// Stays same here too
});

var TableRow = React.createClass({
  // This remains same
});

//Export the table component
export default Table;
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/reactcomponents/table.js"></script>
<div id="loadboardContainer">
 <div class="table-desc">Future Loads</div>
 <div id="futureLoadsContainer"></div>

 <div class="table-desc">Todays Loads</div>
 <div id ="todaysLoadsContainer"></div>

 <div class="table-desc">Active Loads</div>
 <div id ="activeLoadsContainer"></div>
</div>
<script>
 var futureContainer = document.getElementById('futureLoadsContainer');
 var todaysContainer = document.getElementById('todaysLoadsContainer');
 var activeContainer = document.getElementById('activeLoadsContainer');

ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getFutureTableValues.php" />, futureContainer);
ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getTodaysTableValues.php" />, todaysContainer);
ReactDOM.render(<Table source="/reactloadboard/react/getActiveTableValues.php" />, activeContainer);
</script>
```

Comment: It is telling me that the exports is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of making a component reusable with React, but since you recently started learning here few things you can go with.

1. prefer leaning on actual react app instead of browser, but why ? the code you wrote is es5 code and you can write much cleaner and reusable code in ES6.
2. for starting use any boilerplate so you don't have to dive into the webpack and other complex things at beginning.
3. now coming to the point of re-usability, if you use it as webpack, it combines all your code into one js file, which you can implement any where on your website.

Now about your code

check this one , about using separate js file 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

it has one important piece of information

> Note that some browsers (Chrome, e.g.) will fail to load the Separate
>   file unless it's served via HTTP.